# mutating method sent to immutable object while the object is Mutiable

Tags: ios

I have defined my mutable object as

```
NSMutableArray *scribbles;
```

Then in `viewDidLoad` I initialize it

```
scribbles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

After fetching my first JSON page, I add the data into it

```
scribbles = JSON[@"scribbles"];
```

Then later I load the second page and I try adding more data into my array

```
NSMutableArray *mutableJson = [JSON[@"scribbles"] mutableCopy];
[scribbles addObjectsFromArray:mutableJson];
```

but the app crashes and gives me a `mutating method sent to immutable object` error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do:

```
scribbles = [JSON[@"scribbles"] mutableCopy];
```

You don't need to make mutable copy of the second page, so then just do this:

```
[scribbles addObjectsFromArray:JSON[@"scribbles"]];
```

---

To explain:

```
scribbles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // mutable, OK
scribbles = JSON[@"scribbles"]; // immutable, you have to make mutable copy
[scribbles addObjectsFromArray:mutableJson]; // scribbles was immutable, the parameter doesn't need to be mutable
```

Comment: :) this makes so much sense.Thank you! will accept your answer as soon as S.O. lets me

Answer (score 0):

```
scribbles = JSON[@"scribbles"];
```

This line makes your scribbles object immutable. You need to add object instead assigning. If you have more objects you can create mutable array from immutable array like following

```
scribbles = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:JSON[@"scribbles"]];
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of this:

```
[scribbles addObjectsFromArray:mutableJson];
```

do this:

```
scribbles = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:JSON[@"scribbles"]];
```